# Swift Update number of cells in table when slider value changes

Tags: swift, uitableview, uislider

I want to update the number of cells in the table when the slider is moved. I have really no idea how to do that and I didn't found anything that fit to my case. Is there a method?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you want to do is to call `tableView.realodData()` when the slider's value changes.

There are a few methods to catch the slider change event, but usually, one uses the `UISlider's` value changed action.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        updateTableViewNumberOfRows() // update number of rows in this function
                                      // or write the code here, it's up to you
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```